# Singleton factory for managing and wrapping multiple database objects

Tags: php, singleton, adodb

I'm building a PHP application which has to interact with several structurally identical databases. I'd like to use a singleton factory to hand out connections to the databases and minimize the number of duplicate connections. I'd also like to wrap the database class with a few functions.

It would be extremely convenient if I could do all this in a single class. I tried using a singleton factory (it seemed like a good idea at the time), only to realize that it seems like has to return other classes to be useful. Is there an easy way to combine the singleton factory and database wrapping functionality, or should I just put the database wrapping functions in another class?

```
static private $instance = array();

private function __construct($name) {
    switch ($name) {
        //select db connection
    }

    $this->db = $this->getDb();
    return;
}

protected function __clone() {

}

public static function singleton($name) {
    if (!isset(self::$instance[$name])) {
        $c = __CLASS__;
        self::$instance[$name] = new $c($name);
    }
    return self::$instance[$name];
}

public function wrapperFunction() {
    //stuff
}
```

Comment: looked at interfaces? :)

Comment: Please explain the part about the duplicate connections.  Are you going to be connecting to the same database for multiple tasks within the same process?  Tell us a little more detail about what you're doing.

Comment: If I did that, it looks like I'd be splitting a relatively short bit of code into two classes. Also, why use an interface instead of a generic wrapper class?

Comment: @GoalBased It's a system in which users using the same frontend will be connecting to several different databases which have the same table layout, but different data. If multiple users connect to the same database, I'd like to reuse the connection.

Comment: I think I see what you're trying to do...tell me if this is right: you are creating a wrapper class to something like mysqli that will add custom functions. In other words, you are extending an existing DB class.  In addition you want a factory class that will hand out instances of your new class.  Is that right?

Comment: I asked if there was an easy way to do both in the same class.

Comment: I think you need to create two separate classes then.  The first class extends the database class, the second class creates, distributes, and maintains instances of the first class.

I think you'll find this way to be just as convenient as trying to do it all in one class.

Having said that, I don't think you need to make your own factory class to efficiently reuse database connections; I think mysqli's persistent connections should be pretty good at doing that for you.

Comment: [a] It adds another very short class to keep track of (increasing the mental load), so it's not as convenient; hence why I asked the question. [b] I'm not using mysqli, read the tags. [c] A factory is still one of the easiest ways to dole out connections; I assume you're complaining about the singleton part. The singleton also makes it easier to close unused connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this would probably be possible by using some class-wide state variables and doing some clever things with [func_num_args](http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-num-args.php) and [func_get_arg](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-arg.php) in the constructor.

However, in the interest of reducing the [number of WTFs per minute](http://www.osnews.com/story/19266/WTFs_m), I'll go with GoalBased's suggestion of splitting things up into two classes.

Answer (score 1):

I do something similar quite often (Managing multiple database connections by name for example).  The one change I'll suggest is making the constructor and `$instance` array protected.  The reason is that it becomes FAR easier to test that way (since you can extend it with a wrapper class to be able to access them and create and destroy instances as you need to).  Sure, that opens up the possibility for someone to do that in the application, but why throw away the possibility of managing instances from a child class?

Just my $0.02...